# How to change superscript text so that it is displayed in parenthesis in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

How to change superscript text so that it is displayed in parenthesis in Word?

I have a massive amount of interlinear text in the format:  x <sup>y</sup> where y is the translation of the word x.

I would like it to be in the form: x (y) but can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the “Find and Replace” dialog (e.g., type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
and click on the “More >>” button. 
Using the “Format” button in the expanded (“Search Options”) part of the dialog box,
set the “Find What” format to “Superscript”
and the “Replace With” format to “Not Superscript/Subscript”. 
Leave the “Find What” field empty, and enter `(^&)` into the “Replace With” field.

[image: “Find and Replace” dialog with “Search Options”]

This works because `^&` is the code sequence for “Find What Text”;
i.e., insert the text that was found here. 
This is especially useful if you are searching for text that matches a format, as in this case,
or for a wildcard/pattern.